# Getting weird output when trying to print StringBuilder type: "com.jeanlucthumm.poem.Word@7852e922"

Tags: java, class, generics, stringbuilder, erasure

My program aims to create a random poem by repeatedly printing a randomly generated line.
I have a class called Line which has a field line that it operates on:

```
private StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
```

The constructor looks like this:

```
public Line(int length, String pathOfWordList) throws IOException {
    this.length = length;
    populateLine(length, pathOfWordList);
}
```

The word list has three types of words : nouns verbs and adjectives, each with a probability of being selected.

populateLine selects and prepares a word to add to the StringBuilder line. Words are objects of the class Word and have two fields:

```
private Type wordType;
private String word;
```

Where Type is an enum that has the three word types.

Populate line then adds the word by calling a method that calls a method.
The first method has this signature:

```
// currentWord is the word that we have to insert after.
// wordList is the word bank we draw from.
// line is the line we are working with.
// The last two doubles are the probabilities of the three types of words.
// The third one can be inferred
private void getNextWord(Word currentWord, WordList wordList,
        StringBuilder line, double nounProb, double verbProb)
```

That method has a bunch of loops that call this method:

```
// Adds a word to the line and updates its type
// Used by getNextWord
private void loopHelper(Word currentWord, Type type, WordList wordList,
        StringBuilder line) {
    currentWord.setType(type);
    currentWord.setWord(wordList.getWord(type));
    line.append(" " + currentWord);
}
```

Finally for testing purposes I have made a method that prints out the line:

```
public void printPoemLine() {
    System.out.println(this.line.toString());
}
```

But when I instantiate and call that method i get this weird output as the line:

```
com.jeanlucthumm.poem.Word@7852e922 com.jeanlucthumm.poem.Word@7852e922 com.jeanlucthumm.poem.Word@7852e922 com.jeanlucthumm.poem.Word@7852e922 com.jeanlucthumm.poem.Word@7852e922 com.jeanlucthumm.poem.Word@7852e922
```

Can someone tell me what that is? I have only found one other article on the internet that had this type of output and it was dealing with Type Erasure, but I am not sure that applies here.

Comment: Provide a `.toString()` implementation of `Word`. It now shows you the default value specified in `Object` while you want to define something actually meaningful.

Comment: I do that by using the @Override annotation and defining a toString() method right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The annotation is not required but definitely encouraged since it will give you an error should you make a mistake in the method definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing:

```
line.append(" " + currentWord);
```

you're implicitly calling `currentWord.toString()` which returns, by default, a string that looks like: `com.jeanlucthumm.poem.Word@7852e922`
 
which is `<the name of the class>@<hash-code of the object>`